# disabling items of a combo editor depending on a value in the grid

Tags: extjs

I am trying to disable certain items of a combo editor in an editorgrid depending on a value in the   grid row.

The problem with the code below is that it correctly disables the combo items when the combo is first used but it remains the same afterwards.

When I click on the combo the focus event is always fired and the cycle runs and r.data is updated as it should be but the way the combo items are displayed are not changed after the initial display.

Could somebody help me how to fix this?

Thx.

SWK

```
var lifecycle_combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    typeAhead : true,
    mode : 'local',
    triggerAction : 'all',
    valueField : 'value',
    lazyRender : true,
    displayField : 'text',
    store : ref_lifecycle_store,
    listeners : {            
        focus: function(combo, gr, index){
            var lfc=usergrid.activeEditor.record.data.ref_lifecycle;
            ref_lifecycle_store.each(function(r){
                switch(lfc)
                {
                case 'anonymized':
                    if (r.id!='deleted')
                        r.data.selectable=false;
                  break;
                case 'deleted':
                    r.data.selectable=false;
                  break;
                default:
                    if (r.id=='logged_in' || r.id=='some_closed' || r.id=='all_closed')
                        r.data.selectable=false;
                    else
                        r.data.selectable=true;
                }
            });    
        },            
        beforeselect : function(combo, r, index) {                
            return r.get('selectable');
        }
    },
    tpl: '<tpl for=".">' + 
    '<div ext:qtip="{tip}" class="x-combo-list-item ' + 
        '<tpl if="selectable == false">' + 
            'x-combo-list-item-unselectable' + 
        '</tpl>' + 
    '">{text}</div>' + 
    '</tpl>'  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this ExtJs4 or 4? Try to just filter the store you're using in Combobox. It should leave only records that you filtered.

Comment: Its ExtJs 3.4. Thanks for the idea about filtering. At this point I would prefer disabling but I will look at filtering if I finally fail to make disabling to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are taking the field values from the store all the operation done for the field values should be done through store only.. The best way is that you can remove the item by getting it by using getStore and remove it by using removeAt() method

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to display the same set of options for every case, only some options should be disables for some cases. I feel that this would give more reassurance for the user what is happening to him.